# Existe alguna forma de obtener el último dato agregado sin que sea el último de la lista en Firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo una lista de números que dentro tienen ciertos datos, en los cuales voy agregando un valor "Sí" o "No", como en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El último "Sí" que agregué fue el que se encuentra en el número 4, pero si hago un filtro en Firebase con

```
.equalTo("Sí").limitToLast(1)
```

Me regresa el valor del "Sí" posicionado en el número 5 y no en el 4 que fue el último "Sí" que agregué a la base de datos... Existe alguna forma de reconocer el último "Sí", sin la necesidad de que se encuentre en el último puesto de la lista?

Aún no encuentro la solución a esto, espero puedan ayudarme.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando utilizas `limitToLast()` solo se limita al ultimo elemento de una lista bajo un nodo en particular, no sobre la ultima escritura en un nodo.

Para hacer lo que necesitas, deberias guardar en otro nodo el id del ultimo nodo modificado luego del `setValue("si")`, y luego acceder a consultar el dato en esa referencia para saber que valor dentro de `Users` fue el ultimo escrito.